# How to export vertex animation to unity

Tags: animation, export, unity

I created this shape keys animation(using vertex groups), and I want to export in into unity. Id does not work as i supposed, when I follow the tutorial about exporting to unity It works different. I haven't found any description about exporting animation like this to unity. Can you help me with doing this?
My animation:

0 frame
[image: 0 frame]

20 frame
[image: 20 frame]

Comment: Have you tried creating actions with those shapekeys inside? This link may be helpful - [Related](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47709/why-cant-i-have-two-animations-in-one-objects-when-using-property-play-mode/47734#comment81267_47734)

Comment: I think that's too complicated for me. I'm begginer in creating aniamtion with blender :/ There is no simpler way?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe getting some other input would be useful.